# useEffect dependency - using combination as single dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 API calls on a page, and I need to trigger an event on useEffect, only if information from both APIs are exist.

`layoutInfo` object from the first API. `paymentData` from second API

Rather I want to restrict the event to be sent only one time if both `layoutInfo and paymentData` exists.

How do I achieve it? can I use dependencies like [layoutInfo?.layoutId && paymentData]

Comment: `[dependency1, dependency1,]` works great for me. Could you try `console.log` the data from each API? If the `paymentData` returns empty object`{}`, it will be seem as `truthy` in `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple dependencies as they change, useeffect will trigger. Your code should work.
But why dont you use promises in this case. Use Promise.all method for both apis and perform you action once they get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`[transaction?.transId && paymentData]` should work in your case.

By using `[transaction?.transId && paymentData]` as the dependency, the `useEffect` will only be triggered when the condition evaluates to true, i.e., when both `transaction?.transId` and `paymentData` exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).